# TinyIoc - how do I configure all interface registrations AsPerRequestSingleton?

Tags: c#, nancy, tinyioc

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Starts up the Application.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="container">The container.</param>
    /// <param name="pipelines">The pipelines.</param>
    protected override void ApplicationStartup(TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer container, Nancy.Bootstrapper.IPipelines pipelines)
    {
        base.ApplicationStartup(container, pipelines);

        container.Register<UserProvider>().AsPerRequestSingleton();
    }
```

The above is my existing application startup containing my TinyIoc configuration. Is there any way to take all interface registrations and turn them all into PerRequestSingletons? I can't do them 'one by one' as I have too many repositories, and I can't leave them as singletons, because it doesn't work with the way that NHibernate is set up.

Comment: never actually heard of TinyIoc before this. Any reason you chose to use it?

Comment: Its the default IoC provider for Nancy. It works out-of-the-box.

Comment: @Diego Mijelshon I'm not sure why you removed the NHibernate tag, as it was integral to the question. Please explain.

Comment: @MarkWithers how is it integral to the question, other than you wanting to use it for NH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want everything to be request scoped, then try moving the registration into the `ConfigureRequestContainer` method rather than `ApplicationStartup`.

Generally this is how you handle request scoped singletons in Nancy.

Failing that you might need to look at another DI package, eg. http://nuget.org/packages/Nancy.Bootstrappers.Autofac
It has more features and conventions to deal with mass registrations.

Just nuget it, then make your bootstrapper a subclass of the bootstrapper inside the package.

Comment: ConfigureRequestContainer didn't work for me, as it killed the performance (2.8 seconds to register all our classes)

Comment: I've given you the correct answer as I have moved to a different bootstrapper. We went with Windsor, as we've used it before